# Convert a NSDate to milliseconds epoch time

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, epoch

I need to be able to convert a date to a time stamp, an epoch in milliseconds.
All I see online are for converting milliseconds to NSDate and not the other way round. Any help out there?

Answer (score 55):

NSTimeInterval is a double that already contains sub-second data after the decimal point. Depending what you need, your conversion could be a simple as multiplying by 1000.

```
- (void)testDateFormat
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"Time: %f", floor([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000));
    NSLog(@"Time: %f", floor([date timeIntervalSince1970]));
    NSLog(@"Time: %lli", [@(floor([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)) longLongValue]);
    NSLog(@"Time: %lli", [@(floor([date timeIntervalSince1970])) longLongValue]);
}

// Result
// 2013-04-15 13:28:11.284 TestApp[10469:907] Time: 1366057691284.000000
// 2013-04-15 13:28:11.286 TestApp[10469:907] Time: 1366057691.000000
// 2013-04-15 13:28:11.287 TestApp[10469:907] Time: 1366057691284
// 2013-04-15 13:28:11.288 TestApp[10469:907] Time: 1366057691
```

Answer (score 8):

timeIntervalSince1970 will return seconds from 1970. There are other timeIntervalSince methods if needed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970

Answer (score 2):

timeIntervalSince1970 multiply the return value by  1000
because the returned value is in second not in millisecond
kindly check that website for more testing http://currentmillis.com/